# Registering a 2nd component? Vue.js Laravel6

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-6

I have created a fresh Laravel6 project to work out how to register components...

I have cloned **ExampleComponent.vue** to **ExampleComponent2.vue**

// ExampleComponent2.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example2 Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example2 component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component2 mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

// app.js

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('example-component2', require('./components/ExampleComponent2.vue').default);
```

// login.blade.php
- I have placed this under the closing  tag and @endsection to test on the login page...

```
<example-component2></example-component2>
```

I have run "npm run watch" in command line and there are no error messages...

When I load the login route, I open the console to see this error message?

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you
>   register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure
>   to provide the "name" option.
>
> (found in )

How do I register extra components???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > // login.blade.php - I have placed this under the closing tag and @endsection to test on the login page...

You need an element with the id that you defined in your js/app.js:

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app', // you need an element with id="app". Your vue component will replace this
});
```

Then put your component inside that element.

//login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.authentication')

@section('content')

<div id="app">
    <example-component2/>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Ok, I understand. It was npm run watch not working properly. I had to try npm run watch-poll...

If you have 2 components, what do you do?

Comment: You will have to make a main component that contains those two components. e.g., register and mount a component Main.vue in your: `<div id="app"> <main/> </div>`
In your Main.vue's template, put the two components (wrapped by a div, because Vue templates don't allow two root nodes) : `<template> <div> <example-component/> <example-component2/> </div> </template>`